# extjs file uploading - how to handle disconnected from internet or network

Tags: file-upload, extjs, disconnect

We are using an extjs form to upload our files to fileserver ( we have an FileUploadHandler.ashx to handle the file on the bakcend side )

My question is, can extjs handle / throw an exception if accidentally during the upload process the user was disconnected from the network / internet

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which extjs version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to handle that on the server side. I don't believe ExtJS can handle that, it can only handle responses from the server. So, if your server throws a 500 or another error code that indicates that the request was unsuccessful, you can handle that.